# Javascript error for function undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I keep getting a javascript error that my function is not defined. I have checked that the .js file is referenced correctly in the source (other functions in the same .js file are called successfully from this webform). Below is a code snippet of the source and under that is the fuction

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ChildrenAsTriggers="true" ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh All Thumbnails" OnClick="Button1_Click" BorderStyle="None" Height="48px" OnClientClick="ForceThumbnailRefreshAll();" />
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code in the javascript file:

```
function wait(ms) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while (end < start + ms) {
        end = new Date().getTime();
    }
}

function ForceThumbnailRefreshAll() {
    ImageLoadingPanel.Show();
    wait(3000);
    ImageLoadingPanel.Hide();
}
```

Comment: "my function is not defined" — Which function? There are several in that code. What **exactly** is the error message? Quote it instead of vaguely describing it.

Comment: Your `ImageLoadingPanel` is not in the question - is it in your code?  As @Quentin correctly points out - exactly where is your error occurring.  Please read this [mcve] with emphasis on complete and verifiable.